# How to set the execution time of the MoveMouseRelative function in LUA?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I am new to programming and need to ask a question.
So, this code loaded in logitech mouse pulls it down with a given speed :

```
MoveMouseRelative(0,3)
                        Sleep(25)
```

essence of the question: how to set exact time in ms for how long this function will work before switching to another function, maybe like this:

```
MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
                        Sleep(18)
```

So, mouse moving with a one speed for some time and then switching to another speed.
here is the code to fix:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat  
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,3)
                        Sleep(25)

                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
                end             
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end 
end
```

I will be grateful for any support

Comment: You can replace `repeat` loop with `for i=1,10 do` loop to exit the loop after predictable time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MoveMouseRelative` arguments are always integer (the bigger the faster)
`Sleep` argument is recommended to be a multiple of 15 (the smaller the faster)

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   Sleep(10)
   if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
      local t0 = GetRunningTime()
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(0,3)  -- move fast
         Sleep(15)
      until GetRunningTime() > t0 + 500  -- exit this loop after 500 ms
         or not (IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsMouseButtonPressed(1))
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(0,1)  -- move slow
         Sleep(30)
      until not (IsMouseButtonPressed(3) and IsMouseButtonPressed(1))
   end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to influence the exectution time of a function is to either clock the cpu down (which you can't) or to insert idle times.

That's what you're already doing using `sleep`.

Note that timing is often not very accurate. So don't expect microsecond resolution here.